# Selecting dynamically Element id in javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

The code given below does not work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function dosomething(ID){

        var name = document.getElementById(ID).value;
        alert(name);
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="name1" /><input type="button" value="click" onclick="dosomething("name1")" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" id="name2" /><input type="button" value="click" onclick="dosomething("name2")" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you would have created a JsFiddle you would have noticed the issue sooner. (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the quotes not used properly, console should show you the syntax error.

```
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="dosomething("name1")" />
```

to

```
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="dosomething('name1')" />
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZFKZ/)**